# Android listview with a CursorAdapter fastScroll Alphabet bubble

Tags: android, listview, alphabet, fastscroll

I want to create a listview which gets data from a Cursor Adapter and build a fast scroll with alphabet bubbles on the right. What is the best way/libraries to do this with Material design? I want to achieve this in the link below. The Alphabet bubble on the right with the same design.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/67537/1095843/8h5VtFvLlRMOsqI/2015-08-19%20at%209.28%20AM.png

Comment: I think your best bet is to write it from scratch using a custom view

Comment: @inner_class7 Can you please provide some example/tutorial of how to do that?